# How can I add string and create new column in my csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

In my existing CSV file I have a column called "SharePoint ID" and it look like this

```
1.ylkbq
2.KlMNO
3.
4.MSTeam
6.
7.MSTEAM
8.LMNO83
```

and I'm just wondering how can I create a new Column in my CSV call "SharePoint Email" and then add "@gmail.com" to only the actual Id like "ylkbq", "KLMNO" and "LMNO83" instead of applying to all even in the blank space. And Maybe not add/transfer "MSTEAM" to the new Column since it's not an Id.

```
$file = "C:\AuditLogSearch\New folder\OriginalFile.csv"
$file2 = "C:\AuditLogSearch\New folder\newFile23.csv"

$add = "@GMAIL.COM"

$properties = @{
    Name       = 'Sharepoint Email'
    Expression = {
        switch -Regex ($_.'SharePoint ID') {
    
          #Not sure what to do here
        }
    }
}, '*' 
Import-Csv -Path $file | 
Select-Object $properties |
Export-Csv $file2 -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) this is how it could look:

```
$add = "@GMAIL.COM"

$expression = {
    switch($_.'SharePoint ID')
    {
        {[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -or $_ -match 'MSTeam'}
        {
            # Null value or mathces MSTeam, leave this Null
            break
        }
        Default # We can assume these are IDs, append $add
        {
            $_.Trim() + $add
        }
    }
}

Import-Csv $file | Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'SharePoint Email'
    Expression = $expression
} | Export-Csv $file2 -NoTypeInformation
```

**Sample Output**

```
Index SharePoint ID SharePoint Email
----- ------------- ----------------
1     ylkbq         ylkbq@GMAIL.COM
2     KlMNO         KlMNO@GMAIL.COM
3                   
4     MSTeam        
5                   
6     MSTEAM        
7     LMNO83        LMNO83@GMAIL.COM
```

---

A more concise expression, since I misread the point, it can be reduced to just one `if` statement:

```
$expression = {
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'SharePoint ID') -and $_ -notmatch 'MSTeam')
    {
        $_.'SharePoint ID'.Trim() + $add
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Santiago, thank you so much again for this but just wondering How can I NOT include  "MSTeam" in the new column since it's not an actual Id and doesn't have email. Later I'll need to get AzureAD displayName using the new Column so even having "MSTeam" word in the new column might give me a problem/issue later.

Comment: @aaselab that's my bad, I misread, thought you wanted MSTeam there but without appending. See my edit.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but I was doing it the long process of what I wanted to do and only now I found out that there is an easy proccess so would you mind taking a look at my post once again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294010/how-to-modify-column-and-connect-to-sharepoint-using-powershell

I would be really apprecited for your help.